# gradual image size transition for responsive website design

Tags: css, web

I would like to know how to make an image gradually change sizes instead of changing suddenly when the size is changed in media queries for different screen sizes. For example, if an image is 100px wide and gets changed to 500px wide when the screen has a max width of 1000px, how do you apply the transition effect so the image gradually gets smaller instead of just suddenly appearing smaller. I have searched for this answer and I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for. Here is a website example of what I am trying to do. I copied the html and css from this site but can't get the effect to work. The image to look at is the slider images when the screen is reduced in size.

http://www.sensationalteeth.com/

Answer (score 1):

To have a transitioning layout you have to add `transition: all 1s ease;` to the container that changes its size according to different `media-queries`.

Then if you add a `div.image` within with a the follwing CSS properties:

```
background-image: url(some.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 50vh; /* 50% of viewport height */
width: 100%;
```

You should get the desired effect.

## Working [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/v374E/)